# Abbreviate initial name from a list of names in a text file

Tags: text-processing, sed

```
Washington George
Adams John
Jefferson Thomas
Madison James
```

Expected:

```
W. George
A. John
J. Thomas
M. James
```

I have tried to use `sed`. Below are some of the patterns I used after many google searches.

```
\<      # match start of word
\>      # match end of word

's/[^a-z]././'
's/.....\>/./'
```

I have difficulty capturing the letters after the first occurrence until the next word.

Comment: Hi, just wondering if you realize that--while the "names" you've abbreviated are "first" in each line--these particular names you've chosen (Washington, Adams, etc.) are actually "last" names (surnames)? Surnames may require extra checks (imagine names like `McKinley` or `de Gaulle`).

Comment: @jubilatious1 Thats a good call. I wanted to learn how to capture the remaining characters of a word after its 1st character. whether it is a name or word.  I dont understand why they changed my title and also I did not say the names/words were in a text file. One of the solutions uses a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `sed` command:

```bsh
$ sed 's/^\(.\)[^ ]*/\1./' file
W. George
A. John
J. Thomas
M. James
```

Or more succintly:

```bsh
$ sed -E 's/^(.)[^ ]*/\1./' file
W. George
A. John
J. Thomas
M. James
```

What it does:

- Capture the first character `^(.)`.
- Then select the next characters that are not a space `[^ ]*`.
- Replace previous patterns with the captured character and a dot.

The `\1` represents the first capture group: `(.)`. You can have multiple captures, each one will be represented by an incremental number: `\1` fist capture, `\2` second, and so on. The capture is performed by surrounding the pattern with parenthesis, without the `-E` flag escaped with backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to replace the first run of lower-case letters with a dot.

You can do this by matching the first substring of only lower case letters using a basic regular expression.

```
$ sed 's/[[:lower:]]\{1,\}/./' file
W. George
A. John
J. Thomas
M. James
```

Also, most `sed` implementations support extended regular expressions if used with the `-E` option.

```
$ sed -E 's/[[:lower:]]+/./' file
W. George
A. John
J. Thomas
M. James
```

Doing it this way assumes that the names you want to abbreviate all start with an upper-case letter. Fortunately, this is quite common.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
perl6 -pe 's/^^ (\w+) /{$0.comb[0]}./;'
```

Sample Input:

```
Washington George
Adams John
Jefferson Thomas
Madison James
```

Sample Output:

```
W. George
A. John
J. Thomas
M. James
```

Briefly, we use Raku's `s///` substitution operator, asking for matches that start from `^^` beginning-of-line, capturing the first `\w+` word with `(…)` into the `$0` capture variable. In the replacement, instruct Raku to execute code inside the `{…}` curly braces, here `comb`-ing the `$0` capture variable to individual letters then taking the `[0]` first one, finally printing a literal `.` period afterwards.

You could (of course) simply capture one letter, demanding that it be uppercase:

```
raku -pe 's/^^ (<upper>) \w* /$0./;'
```

The second example code (immediately above) gives the same output from the OP's Sample Input, but also has the advantage of leaving (uncapitalized) names like the "de" in `de Gaulle Charles` untouched.

https://docs.raku.org/syntax/s$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS
https://raku.org